# Android studio 1.0.1 - material as default?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, material-design

I installed android studio 1.0.1 and when creating new apps, material design is set by default. I tried to generate new theme with "Android Action Bar Style Generator", which worked perfectly fine a few months ago, now it doesn't do anything. Sort of material design is set by default. Where is appcompat and how to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Appcombat v20+ is using material design as default. You can try to use older version of this library, but I recommend you to not resist progress.